# Angular 4 infinite array loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use *ngFor and repeat my array elements myltiple times. Like this:

In component:

```
letters: Array<string> = [a, b, c, d, e];
currentLetter: string= c;
```

In template:

```
<div *ngFor="let letter of letters" (click)="currentLetter = letter">{{letter}}</div>
```

And I wanna to see something like this in render:

a, b, c, d, e

And after click on 'a':

d, e, a, b, c

And after click on 'e':

c, d, e, a, b

Any ideas? :)
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it will resolve your problem**

```
 <div *ngFor="let letter of letters" (click)="myMethod(letter)">{{letter}}
</div>


myMethod(selectedLetter){
    let postLen = 3; // configurable
    let i=0, len =str1.length;
    let foundFlag = false;
    let arr1 = [], arr2 = [], arr3 = [];
    for(;i<len;i++){
         if(str1[i] == selectedLetter){
             for(k=0;k<postLen && (i+k)< len ; k++){
                arr1.push(str1[i+k]);
                i++;
             }
             foundFlag = true;
         }else if(!foundFlag){
                arr2.push(str1[i]);
         }else{
                arr3.push(str1[i]);
         }

    }

    this.letters = arr3.concat(arr2);
    this.letters = this.letters.concat(arr1);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two lists with `ngIf`: the first list renders the letters before `currentLetter` or `currentLetter` itself, while the second list renders the letters after `currentLetter`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let letter of letters; index as i">
  <button *ngIf="i>=letters.indexOf(currentLetter)" (click)="currentLetter = letter">{{letter}}</button>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngFor="let letter of letters; index as i">
  <button *ngIf="i<letters.indexOf(currentLetter)" (click)="currentLetter = letter">{{letter}}</button>
</ng-container>
```

[image: result1]
[image: result2]